# MOSFET FDN337N faulty (shorted)

Tags: nmos, pmos

We have a circuit like the attached.
If the "+18V" was connected and the "power_on" was left(forgot, since they are from two different connectors) unconnected. FDN337N will became faulty. And the circuit will be switch on Vcc = +18V since D and S of FDN337N became short circuit.
Could anyone give me an advice on how to improve this circuit?
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: As VoltageSpike says. Plus you may add an ESD protection diode in parallel with R10 in case of incidents while plugging in the POWER ON connector.

Comment: What is Vcc? how high does it get?

Comment: Vcc is about +18V

Answer (score 1):

It should be fine, the pulldown resistor (R10) will hold the gate low under any circumstance (assuming you have a good ground, the pcb layout could be making a difference here).

T2 will always be off and because T2 is off, the gate to T1 will be high and T1 should always be on.

Under normal conditions T2 (FDN337N) would not short circuit unless some absolute maximum value was exceeded. This typically happens while prototyping if ESD hits the gate.

I would replace the FDN337N using proper ESD and thermal/soldering procedures. the circuit should work as described.

Comment: Thank you VoltageSpike. I have checked the pcb and the grounding is ok.
I have tried once to replaced the FDN337N, since we are still working at the prototyping stage of the instrument, I once forgot to connect the "power_on" connector while with the "+18V" connected and the FDN337N became faulty again.
I will try again to replace FDN337N with an ESD protection diode PESD3V6Z1BCSF. Thank you user_1818839 as well.

Comment: Make sure you are also not more than 30V across Vds and that the gate is always lower than 8V to ground

Comment: ok. Thanks, Voltage Spike.

Comment: When T2 is off, T1 should be off as well since it is a P-channel type…